# how to update the source of an embedded svg element

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I've got an svg image stored on s3. I'm embedding it in a web page using the `object` tag, like so.

```
 <object
    type="image/svg+xml"
    data="https://bucket.actual_url_to_amazon_s3_bucket"
    id="graph-svg"></object>
```

So far, nice and simple. Now sometimes the user makes changes and I want to show them a different svg. I want to just update the source of the object tag, same as I could with an `img` tag.

While this technically works, and the new svg is loaded, I get weird rendering issues -- the size of the svg is all wrong and truncated. I discovered that if I remove the object tag from the DOM, then update the data, then add it back to the DOM it renders fine.

html:

```
<div id="svgcont">
  <object
    type="image/svg+xml"
    data="https://bucket.actual_url_to_amazon_s3_bucket.svg"
    id="graph-svg"></object>
</div>
```

js:

```
// make an api call to get the new svg url and then:
var ob = $("#graph-svg").remove();
ob.attr("data", newSVGurl); 
$("#svgcont").prepend(ob);
```

If I do the above I get the svg displayed as I like. But just directly calling

```
ob.attr("data", newSVGurl)
```

Is there a way to directly tell the object "refresh your source data", or force it to re-render or whatever it does when it's inserted into the DOM, without actually removing it and then re-inserting it?

The problem with the removal is it looks weird and jumpy, and it makes the image flash and other items on the page jump around a bit. So I'm hoping for something that looks smoother and less like a glitch.

Comment: You could try to load the new object in the background and then replace it. 
Any replace will look jumpy, preferably add an animation to make it look smooth.

Comment: can you provide some test data like two svgs and their dimensions in codepen or jsbin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked into your question at some length and it seems to be difficult (perhaps impossible) to do better than what I came up with the code below.

My solution sets a width and height on the wrapping div that is equal to the width and height of the object being replaced. It then replaces the object and removes the width and height again. This prevents the text from collapsing and expanding when swapping out the objects.

The image itself unfortunately still flickers somewhat. I haven't been able to fix that issue. Creating an object in JavaScript without appending it to the document does not trigger a load of the image. Appending it to an invisible div and waiting for the load event and then moving it to the target div works, but still has the flicker that I was trying to prevent.

Anyway, here's the code. Oh and here's a [Pen](https://codepen.io/jormaturkenburg-the-typescripter/pen/vPzPER) with the same code.
Click on 'Replace SVG!'

```js
urls = [
  "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/debian.svg",
  "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/ubuntu.svg",
  "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/jquery.svg",
  "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/json.svg"
];
index = 0;

let doTheBusiness = () => {
  index = index + 1 > urls.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1;
  let url = urls[index];
  let invisibleDiv = document.getElementById("my-invisible-div");
  let newObject = document.createElement("object");
  newObject.setAttribute("type", "image/svg+xml");
  newObject.setAttribute("data", urls[index]);
  let oldObject = document.querySelector("#my-wrapper object");
  let bBox = oldObject.getBoundingClientRect();
  let w = bBox.width;
  let h = bBox.height;
  let parent = oldObject.parentNode;
  parent.style.width = `${w}px`;
  parent.style.height = `${h}px`;
  // parent.removeChild(oldObject);
  parent.replaceChild(newObject, oldObject);
  newObject.onload = () => {
    parent.style.width = null;
    parent.style.height = null;
    newObject.onload = null;
  };
};
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#my-invisible-div {
  position: absolute;
  right: -10000px;
  top: -10000px;
}

#my-wrapper {
  padding: 0px;
}

object {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <button onclick="doTheBusiness()">Replace SVG!</button>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    <div id="my-wrapper">
      <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/debian.svg"></object>
    </div>
    <p>
      It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
      content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various
      versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="my-invisible-div">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This was helpful, thanks! I made some improvements -- I found that you don't need to create a new object in the dom, you can actually replaceNode with the original object, which causes the browser to reload the data. Using boundingClientRect() to get the dimensions and then set the parent dimensions is ++.